# Conditional expectation (with average errors)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

In *Mathematical Statistics: Basic Ideas and Selected Topics (Kjell A. Doksum, Peter J. Bickel)*, problem 2.2.29 (a) asks:

> Let $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_{n+1}$ be i.i.d. with mean zero and $Y_i = \mu + \epsilon_i/2 + \epsilon_{i+1}/2 $ for some fixed $\mu$ and $i=1,...,n+1$.
> Show that:
> $$\mathbb{E}[Y_{i+1} \mid Y_1, ..., Y_i] = \mu/2 + Y_i/2 $$

I can solve it once I know that $\mathbb{E}[Y_{i+1} \mid Y_1, ..., Y_i] = \mathbb{E}[Y_{i+1} \mid Y_i]$. But how do you show $\mathbb{E}[Y_{i+1} \mid Y_1, ..., Y_i] = \mathbb{E}[Y_{i+1} \mid Y_i]$ ?

Please prove it very formally and not with any "intuition". Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I am not sure it is true (suppose the $\epsilon_i =\pm 1$ with equal probability, and compare the case where $Y_i=\mu$ and $Y_{i-1}=\mu-1$ and the case where $Y_i=\mu$ and $Y_{i-1}=\mu+1$), but even if it were then we would hope you could show what you have tried.

Comment: If it was false then the whole exercise was false. But actually I agree that it is false. As you said, consider $\epsilon_i = \pm 1$ with equal probability. Then consider $\mu=0, i=2, \epsilon_1 = +1, \epsilon_2 = +1, \epsilon_3 = -1$. Hence $Y_1 = 1, Y_2 = 0$. When we know both $Y_1,Y_2$ then we know $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \epsilon_3$. Hence $E[Y_3 | Y_1,Y_2] = -0.5 $. But $E[Y_3 | Y_2] = 0$. Or did I make a mistake?